# Symfony retrieve data from Array Collection

Tags: php, symfony, arraycollection

In Symfony I am using a query to retrieve all questions and their relative answers from a database. Using a `for` in twig I am trying to display in a table all questions with the relative answers row by row. At the moment I am able to access and display the questions only but not the answers. 
The relation between my entities `Questions and Answers` is (one to many) thus when retrieving the question, also the answers are retrieved. Using dump, I can see the the answers are put in an Array Collection.

Trying to get only a single question from the database with another query, using the `getAnswers()` function from my `Question` entity I am able to get the answers from the array collection using this statement:

```
$answer = $question->getAnswers()->getValues();
```

Using this statement I tried to get the answers for all the questions using the bellow code in the controller, but I get this error:

> Error: Call to a member function getAnswers() on a non-object

I believe this is because the query returns multiple questions and not just one.
How can I get the answers for each individual question from the Array Collection? Thanks in advance for the help.

Controller Code:

```
$question = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('QuizBundle:Question')
            ->findByIdJoinedToCategory();
return $this->render('QuizBundle:Default:admin.html.twig', array('data' => $question));
```

Question Repository:

```
public function findByIdJoinedToCategory()
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT a, q FROM QuizBundle:Question a
                JOIN a.answers q');
        try {
            return $query->getResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Twig Code:

```
{% for item in data %}
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ item.id }}</th>
                    <td>{{ item.image }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.question }}</td>
                    <td></td>
                <tr>
               <tbody>

{% endfor %}
```

Dump screenshot of the data from the query:

[image: Query Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Twig and according to your doctrine query, you can display your questions/answers like this :

```
{% for item in data %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ item.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ item.image }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.question }}</td>
            {% for answer in item.answers %}
                {{ answer.id }}
            {% endfor %}
        <tr>
    <tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

Btw, if it exists a relation between the two entities Question and Answer and you want to display all the questions and their associative answers, you can directly doing this :

In your controller:

```
$questions = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('QuizBundle:Question')->findAll();
return $this->render('QuizBundle:Default:admin.html.twig', array('data' => $questions));
```

In your Twig :

```
{% for question in data %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ question.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ question.image }}</td>
            {% for answer in question.answers %}
                {{ answer.id }}
            {% endfor %}
        <tr>
    <tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I get this error: `Impossible to access an attribute ("answers") on a string variable ("Q1_Question1") in QuizBundle:Default:admin.html.twig at line 28`